# Unable to extract zip in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, zip, archive

Downloading zip folder from server and try to extract the zip but the zip has multiple directory. I can download the zip but not able to extract it.Below code is working when zip has multiple image file but in my case has multiple directories and have multiple files.

```
String _localZipFileName = 'archive.zip';

  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    //url==http://115.166.142.178:3000/staff/syncdata
    var req = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(url));
    Log.e("DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY",_dir);
    var file = File('$_dir/$fileName');
    return file.writeAsBytes(req.bodyBytes);
  }

  Future<void> _downloadZip(String _zipPath) async {
setState(() {
  _downloading = true;
});

Log.e("Zippath",_zipPath);
_images.clear();
_tempImages.clear();
var zippedFile = await _downloadFile(_zipPath, _localZipFileName);
Log.e("Zippath",zippedFile.path);
await unarchiveAndSave(zippedFile);
setState(() {
  _images.addAll(_tempImages);
  _downloading = false;
});
  }



 unarchiveAndSave(var zippedFile) async {
    var bytes = zippedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

for (var file in archive) {
  var fileName = '$_dir/${file.name}';
  if (file.isCompressed) {
    var outFile = File(fileName);
    Log.e('File:: ' , outFile.path);
   // _tempImages.add('${outFile.path}/productImages');
    outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
    await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
  }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The archive package has the [extractFileToDisk](https://pub.dev/documentation/archive/latest/archive_io/extractFileToDisk.html) method which should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried to do that in Dart, however i had similar issues with another languages.
Usualy the issue appears if you forget to verify what type of file you are handling.
file object should have boolean variables `file.isFile` and `file.isDirectory`

you can try to follow this [example](http://www.programmersought.com/article/37592063882/)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart';

var path = p.Context(style: Style.posix);
final String __filename = Platform.script.path.replaceFirst('/', '');
final String __dirname = Directory(__filename).parent.path;

  // read Zip file from disk
  List<int> bytes = File(path.join(__dirname, 'test-a-master.zip')).readAsBytesSync();

     // decode Zip file
  Archive archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

     // Extract the contents of Zip compressed archive to disk
  for (ArchiveFile file in archive) {
    String filename = file.name;
    String decodePath = path.join(__dirname, filename);
    if (file.isFile) {
      List<int> data = file.content;
      File(decodePath)
        ..createSync(recursive: true)
        ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
    } else {
      Directory(decodePath)..create(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

hope it will help you

Comment: `ArchiveFile` giving the file name of parent zip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Dart might not support extracting .zip files out of the box.

I found a package, that handles zip extraction: https://pub.dev/packages/archive/example

Comment: i found the issue . the issue was zip containing zip.